# Looking for Italian military record of ancestor

Tags: military-records, world-war-1, italy

I am looking for some help to attain a military record for Luigi Gascone.

I believe he was with the Alpini 1st mountain artillery battery 1st Regiment Turin “Susa”
Service anything from 1906-1935 as a guess as I have two photos one stating 1926 and another with him and another soldier holding up a hat saying 1906

I believe he was from a small town called Susa outside Turin and was in the Piedmont region if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FamilySearch.org lists a document set called "Documenti militari. Circondario di Torino, 1804-1910." These are the "military muster rolls and draft lists from the province of Torino" (Turin). The catalog note indicates that the date of the roll is generally the year of birth of the draftee.

This may have your Luigi Gascone in it. The records are digitized, but can be viewed only at an LDS Family History Center.
https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/651761

Comment: Hi thanks for reply I’m not sure I fully understand I’ve clicked on the link you have provided but it doesn’t seem to take me anywhere, is this a paid site or do I have to write off to them sorry I have no idea what I’m doing, lol

Comment: Hi, FamilySearch is free, but you do need to have an account there. All they ask is an email address.

Comment: Thanks I have been given his date of birth now it appears to be 21 may 1906 so he won’t appear on that list I would imagine as too young if we assume he joined at 18 that’s 1924 so could be looking fir 1924 - ww2

Comment: @Yogi82 I think he would be on the 1906 roll. The catalog note indicates that the date of the roll is generally the **year of birth** of the draftee.